# Dialogflow - Multiple Yes / No Questions not staying in context

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to setup a structure in the Dialogflow console that involves multiple yes / no questions. It looks like something like this:

```
Agent: do you want to go to Basel?

If User: No -> Agent: Do you want to go to Zurich?

        If User: Yes: Great, you chose Zurich!

If User: Yes -> Agent: Great, you chose Basel!
```

Basically, it keeps asking questions based on something like a location and when the user says Yes, it responds with with the chosen location.

If the user says yes for the first question everything works fine. However, when the user responds with yes for a followup question, Dialogflow still maps the intent of the first question and responds with:

```
Great, you chose Basel!
```

Instead of:

```
Great, you chose Zurich!
```

In the image you can see my intent structure from the Dialogflow console.
[IntentStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0znMh.png)

Does anyone have any recommendations here? I am aware that the mutliple yes / no questions all contain the same examples, but how can I make sure that Dialogflow stays in context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest not to keep all your intents as a follow-up intent. Instead, you can manage all your contexts. What you have to do is that create an intent for each location and two follow-up intent "Yes" and "No". If the user responds with yes show the message else add your next question to the no follow-up intent response and set its output context for the new location "yes" follow-up intent. Similarly, you can create a chain.